# Getting the guild owner in JDA raising NullPointerException

Tags: java, discord-jda

I was trying to make a function which displays info about the server.

```
public static void serverInfo(Guild guild, MessageChannel channel) {
EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();

//Calculations
int people = 0;
int roles = 0;
int tc = 0;
int vc = 0;

for (Member member : guild.getMembers()) {
    if (!member.getUser().isBot())
        ++people;
}
for (Role ignored : guild.getRoles())
    ++roles;
for (TextChannel ignored : guild.getTextChannels())
    ++tc;
for (VoiceChannel ignored : guild.getVoiceChannels())
    ++vc;

String time = String.valueOf(guild.getTimeCreated());
String created = time.substring(8, 10) + "-" + time.substring(5, 7) + "-" + time.substring(0, 4);

embed.setTitle(guild.getName());
embed.setThumbnail(guild.getIconUrl());
embed.addField("Total Members", String.valueOf(guild.getMemberCount()+1), true);
embed.addField("Members", String.valueOf(people),true);
embed.addField("Bots", String.valueOf((guild.getMemberCount()+1)-people), true);
embed.addField("Owner", Objects.requireNonNull(guild.getOwner()).getUser().getName(), true);
embed.addField("Roles", String.valueOf(roles), true);
embed.addField("Text Channels", String.valueOf(tc), false);
embed.addField("Voice Channels", String.valueOf(vc), true);
embed.addField("Date Created", created, false);

channel.sendMessageEmbeds(embed.build()).queue();
}
```

However, this raises a NullPointerException

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)  at
> com.television.Commands.Infos.serverInfo(Infos.java:38)   at
> com.television.CommandExecutor.onMessageReceived(CommandExecutor.java:19)

But, if I removed this part from the function, it works just fine, and no exception is raised.

```
for (Member member : guild.getMembers()) {
        if (!member.getUser().isBot())
            ++people;
}
```

Why does this happen? This problem also gets raised only in 1 server, out of the 3 servers I've tested in.
And, secondly, I know this is not much related to the question from the title, how can I calculate the number of members/bots because this part (the for-each loop in the code snippet above) does not calculate the number of members correctly, it always has 1 as the value of the bot variable, and therefore number of members - 1 is the value of people.

Answer (score 0):

Two things in advance: You have to either cache all the members from every guild or instead (recommended) retrieve them when needed. To be able to do so, you need to enable the GUILD_MEMBERS *Privileged* Intent.

You can pretty easily retrieve a List representing all members of a guild with the following method:

```
public CompletableFuture<List<Member>> loadMembersFull(Guild guild) {
    CompletableFuture<List<Member>> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    if (guild.isLoaded()) {
        future.complete(guild.getMembers());
    } else {
        guild.loadMembers()
            .onError(future::completeExceptionally)
            .onSuccess(future::complete);
    }
}
```

With that you can then move on with all your other stuff.
I actually don't know why it would work without the for-loop, but it looks like the error does not occur there, but when loading the owner, as it throws the exception in your #requireNonNull.
The owner object is null when he/she is no longer in the guild or not yet loaded. The owner could also have deleted the account or get banned by Discord.
To also solve this problem, I recommend you to replace your line with the following one:

```
embed.addField("Owner", Optional.ofNullable(guild.getOwner()).map(owner -> owner.getUser().getName()).orElse("<not found>"), true);
```

To get the proper amount of users, you should filter the list of users for whether they are bots or not.

```
int amount = (int) loadMembersFull(guild).join().stream()
    .map(Member::getUser)
    .filter(user -> !user.isBot())
    .count();
```

If you need more help, feel free to ask me on my [Discord server](https://discord.gg/AKu75JzugX)

Comment: What is the future variable in the code you wrote for loading the guild members

Comment: Sorry for forgetting this code snippet. I have now rewritten it to an entire method that returns a list of all members of the Guild. Depending on the MemberCachePolicy these members are then also kept in the cache.